# Report that shows the last date sent per contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, subscriber, custom-reports

I would like to remove dormant subscribers from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. To that end, is there a way to build a report that can show me "last send date" and "total sends" by subscribers?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE! This question is not quite up to the expected quality. I would recommend adding in more information on your use case, as well as anything you have already tried or discovered and why it doesn't or won't work. See here for more info: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can query the _Sent data view:

Data View: Sent
Query this data view in Automation Studio to find the subscribers sent emails from your Marketing Cloud account.

[_Sent data view doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)